# How to prove two equivalence classes are disjoint?

Tags: equivalence-relations

I know how to prove when the two equivalence classes are not disjoint, i.e. $[a]=[b]$. I see that the proof works for proving a equivalence class is disjoint, but I don't get it. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have two equivalence classes $[a]\not=[b]$. We'll show they are disjoint. Suppose $x\in[a]\cap[b]$. Then, $x\sim a$ and $x\sim b$. By symmetry, $a\sim x$, and hence, by transitivity, $a\sim b$. Therefore, $[a]=[b]$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: So it is the same proof that I was referring to, but with the added contradiction.

Comment: Pretty much. You can basically prove both in one shot. Either $[a]\cap [b]=\emptyset$, or there is some $x\in[a]\cap[b]$, in which case, we get that $[a]=[b]$.

Comment: It's not really a proof by contradiction. This is a direct proof that if two classes intersect, they are identical.